# Configuration Manager returns Null instead of Connection string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to retrieve the string connections from App.config as i see on tutorials

but i cant see app.config in my visual studio.

i clicked the project name as in the picture

[image]

this tab opened and typed the following code

[image]

this is the C# code that get the connection string

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string name)
{
    string returnValue = null;

    ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];

    if (settings != null)
        returnValue = settings.ConnectionString;

    return returnValue;
            
}
```

still, i only get null instead of my desired connection string i'm so confused

i tried the same code on winforms and console but no good

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What kind of project do you actually want to create?

Comment: I'm learning about data access and i heard that putting the connection string directly into the code is a bad idea and should be put into App.Config.  This project was intented to be in winforms but i created the Console project to see if something is wrong about my winform applicaion

Comment: If you're doing it in winforms it's slightly different ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.config file is missing in your project
right click on the project configuration file and name it as app.config once added it will be shown in your project like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lwW0.png)

and add below code to the app.config and replace connectionstring with your
connectionstring value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5CFB.png)

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me from endless headache ;)